# Facebook data deletion callback giving "Unable to confirm request was received"

Tags: php, facebook

api.php

```
<?php
    function base64_url_decode( $input ) {
        return base64_decode( strtr( $input, "-_", "+/" ) );
    }
    function parse_signed_request( $signed_request, $secret ) {
        list( $encoded_sig, $payload ) = explode( ".", $signed_request, 2 );

        // decode the data
        $sig = base64_url_decode( $encoded_sig );
        $data = json_decode( base64_url_decode( $payload ), true );

        // confirm the signature
        $expected_sig = hash_hmac( "sha256", $payload, $secret, $raw = true );
        if( $sig !== $expected_sig ) {
            error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
            return null;
        }

        return $data;
    }
    $secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $data = parse_signed_request( $_POST[ "signed_request" ], $secret );
    $openID = $data[ "user_id" ];
    require( "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php" );
    $mail = new PHPMailer;// To load the French version
    $mail->setLanguage( "zh", 'PHPMailer/language/phpmailer.lang-zh.php');
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->isSMTP();                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";                            // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "xxx@xxx.xxx";                    // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";                    // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                    // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                            // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->setFrom( "xxx@xxx.xxx", "xxx" );
    $mail->addAddress( "xxx@xxx.xxx" ); 
    $mail->Subject = "Facebook API";
    $mail->Body = $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] . json_encode( $data );
    $mail->send();
    $data = [
        "code" => "200"
    ];
    $query = http_build_query( $data );
    $statusURL = "https://xxx.xxx/deletion.php?$query";
    header( "Content-Encoding: utf-8" );
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    $data = [
        "url" => $statusURL,
        "confirmation_code" => "200",
    ];
    echo json_encode( $data );
    exit;
?>
```

deletion.php

```
<?php   
    require( "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php" );
    $mail = new PHPMailer;// To load the French version
    $mail->setLanguage( "zh", 'PHPMailer/language/phpmailer.lang-zh.php');
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->isSMTP();                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";                            // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "xxx@xxx.xx";                    // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxx";                    // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                    // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                            // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->setFrom( "xxx@xxx.xxx", "xxx" );
    $mail->addAddress( "xxx@xxx.xxx" ); 
    $mail->Subject = "Facebook deletion";
    $mail->Body = $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] . json_encode( $_REQUEST );
    $mail->send();
?>
200
```

facebook data deletion request response
[image]
E-mail record
[image]

I has been try sent email to log when facebook or testing user call the api.php or deletion.php. Then, the mail have api.php record only.
Also, I has been try Postman to post api.php, the json response is match fackbook doc request.
Please let me know how To show success or deletion.php url on facebook response should be.

Comment: Which one of the two script URLs did you input as the Data Deletion Callback URL in your app settings?

Comment: The `$statusURL` value you are creating there makes little sense, you append the same `?code=200` query string every time. This is supposed to be a unique URL for each user, where they can check on the status of their deletion request - so you need to pass something, that allows you to _identify_ this particular user.

Comment: @CBroe This is testing the callback function only, For this app , the mode is development. Live app is using data deletion instructions url. I want to prepare data deletion callback, so, I use the testing app to try callback function.

Comment: @CBroe The api.php is data deletion callback url, facebook request return url(deletion.php) for user checking on the status. But I would like to know how to show success or pass the deletion.php to user should be.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is unclear. You are supposed to return a JSON that contains a URL where the user can check on the status of their deletion request, and a confirmation code.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I has been return the JSON that contains a dome URL where the user can check on the status of their deletion request, and a dome confirmation code at sent out email to my email address later. You can seed that the last of api.php has JSON header and echo data array encode by JSON.

Comment: Just because you wrote the code, doesn't necessarily mean it does a 100% what you intended. You'll have to do a bit of debugging then. I'd start by checking if the error log has anything to say, and if not, maybe log what request parameters you receive.

Comment: @CBroe I has been use postman to check the response. The response is { "url": "https://xxx.xxx/deletion.php?code=200", "confirmation_code": "200" } and content-type is application/json. That is match facebook request { url: '<url>', confirmation_code: '<code>' } format. And than, I has been sent the encode request parameters to my email, you can see the E-mail record image.

Comment: The coment system will remove the https://

Comment: `Content-Encoding: utf-8` - that is not a thing. The [`Content-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) header specifies, which _compression_ method you might have applied to your data (gzip, deflate, ...) `utf-8` is not a content encoding. Remove that line.

Comment: @CBroe Oh, you are right. Removed the Content-Encoding header specifies, I can get the success message. Thank you, I appreciate your help very much.